# How to interpret this line in binary for this STM32 HAL function?

Tags: c, embedded

The following line of code sets(to logic 1) pin 12 of port D in an STM32 microcontroller:

[image]

The middle argument of the above HAL function is GPIO_PIN_12 and when I hover on it shows:

```
((uint16_t)0x1000)
```

It seems the above line sets bit 12 as one. But how does the above line do that? what does uint16_t do over 0x1000 so that we can relate it to bit 12?

Comment: The uint16_t is a type-cast. It doesn't do anything to the constant except provide semantics that the compiler may need elsewhere. There will be a typedef somewhere that specifies (declares) exactly what type is meant by that symbol. It's compiler-specific, though. On some compiler+target combos, it will be 'unsigned long int' semantics. On others, just 'unsigned int'. On still others 'unsigned short int'. Etc. If you go look at the source code for that function, you can unravel what that parameter does in intimate detail. Probably just specifies a port mask.

Answer (score 2):

0x1000 is 0001000000000000 in binary, which looks a lot like bit 12 to me.

I would guess (without actually reading it) that HAL_GPIO_Write_Pin does something that amounts to

```
void HAL_GPIO_Write_Pin (volatile uint32_t * port, uint16_t bit, uint32_t value){
  if (value) 
    *port |= bit
  else 
    *port &= ~bit;
}
```

Or something like that, maybe combined with a load of fluff to make sure the port is configured for output. It might for example be taking an index into a table rather then a raw pointer for the port address, but whatever, the essential bit twiddling will likely be something like this.

Comment: What does 1u stand for in your code?

Comment: It's the same as `1 << bit` but the `u` specifies _unsigned_. Whether the unsigned is explicitly needed or not is, I think, part of the heart of the OP question.

Comment: It makes the integer literal 1 unsigned, always a good idea to be explicit about this when using the shift operator in C as it avoids some un or implementation defined behaviours (particularly with shift right where sign extension is waiting to screw you). Note however that I have updated my answer, that would have been right for passing in 12 for bit 12...

Comment: For clarity, I would suggest that you delete the part of your answer that you later realized was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

uint16_t declares the ‘type’ as in a value that is represented as an unsigned 16 bit value. As for bit 12 being set, then the hexadecimal value 0x1000 is binary 0001000000000000
(Count those bits!) . Or we could wrjte (1<<12) that the compiler will evaluate for us. - ‘get the 1 bit and shift it left 12 times’.

Comment: What happens if uint16_t  were omitted? Is that done to explicitly say we are dealing with 16 bit register?

Comment: Does ST define the first pin as 0 (instead of 1)? I would have expected `GPIO_PIN_12` to be 0x0800.

Comment: @JYelton If I write GPIO_PIN_0 then when I hover it shows ((uint16_t)0x1001)

Comment: @GNZ Thanks - I was having a memory lapse thinking the first pin should be 1 instead of 0, but it's typically 0 even on the MCUs I use. Doh!

Comment: @GNZ Without the uint16_t, a literal like 0x1000 would be of type signed int. [Bitwise operations on signed values can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined)

Comment: @JYelton Ports on microcontrollers are almost always enumerated starting with 0.